# Flutter Module compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

**I know this question has been asked a lot, but I seem to try everything and yet that everything fails, and I have no clue why.**

I am building my flutter app as an `.apk` for release, and get several errors stating: `Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0`.

My `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

My `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip
```

**I tried:**

- Changing gradle version to the newest one(8.3.0) in `build.gradle`: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'`. I get an error:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.3.0/gradle-8.3.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.3.0/gradle-8.3.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :

- Changing the kotlin version in `build.gradle` to the expected version: `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'`. I also get an error:

  `Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.`
- Changing the package version to an older one in `gradle-wrapper.properties`: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip`, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I am lost as nothing helps that I found online.
I hope I can find an answer here.